# Is it possible to crack a CRC value for short text validation when someone tries to change a readable text?

Tags: authentication, data-validation

I'd like to validate message texts with CRC-8/16/32 but I'm afraid that they could be changed to another one (for example, adding a "No" at the beginning). There will be no special characters besides the usual ones (? , . ; ª º + =...) and the number of bytes will be counted as well.
The messages will not be encrypted.

Comment: I think a better question would be how to secure the text in your scenario. But that would require some more information on what you are trying to accomplish and what you are protecting against.

Comment: See also [Checksum vs. Hash: Differences and Similarities?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/194600/checksum-vs-hash-differences-and-similarities)

Comment: yes, it's possible, in some cases at least, and it's (relatively) a lot faster to find matches than with a hash. that said, it's still unlikely to be able to quickly and cheaply find such false-positives.